# Java Thread Count doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

Why is count 0?

I start the thread 1 then I start thread 2. Count should be 2000. But it shows count to be 0. Someone please explain in simple terms.

```
public class App {
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doWork();
    }

    public void doWork(){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0;i < 10000;i++){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0;i < 10000;i++){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait for the threads to run. after `t2.start();` add `t1.join(); t2.join();`

Comment: Your code has several problems.  As for the immediate question, my guess is that those threads haven't actually started executing.  More important perhaps is that your `count` variable is not thread safe, i.e. the two threads could interleave when incrementing it, giving incorrect results.

Comment: why haven't the threads started executing? Isn't start() suppose to execute them? Why do I have to wait with t1.join() and t2.join() ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The point of this exercise is probably to illustrate that exact behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time you're printing out your thread count, the threads have not finished executing yet.

To demonstrate, add a `Thread.sleep()` instruction before printing out the thread count:

```
public class App {
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        App app = new App();
        app.doWork();
    }

    public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count); // Count is: 20000
    }
}
```

Also note that operations on primitives are not thread-safe and that the `count++` operation is not [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability). You should synchronize access to your `count` variable, or use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) instead of an `int`. As it stands, you might end up with a count anywhere between zero and 20,000.

Comment: Is `count++` thread safe?  What would happen if the bytecode for `count++` could interleave for the the threads?  Could this lead to an incorrect final count, or even a final count of zero?

Comment: ok so the thread hasn't started but why hasn't it started? t1.start() should start it so why wait?

Comment: @Tim , its not necessary when you called start method it will be started.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Operations on primitives are not thread-safe. Should use an `AtomicInteger` instead of an `int`, but I'm sure you knew that :)

Comment: @JoshBauss Have not started is maybe the wrong way of putting it. I'll update my answer to "have not finished executing yet".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen even if the execution hasn't been finished should count be more than 0? I get it that I have to wait but I still don't see the underlying reason why it has to be done like that.

Comment: @JoshBauss Depends on how the JVM schedules execution of the threads. It's not under your control, although you can influence it by setting the thread's priority.

Comment: I believe this is causing race condition. For me the count comes to 11065

Comment: @DevendraLattu Indeed. It's caused by the `count` variable not being thread-safe, as noted at the end of my answer.

Comment: That's correct @RobbyCornelissen, however, as per my understanding, the count is an instance variable, and both the threads are trying to update the value of count at the same time. Therefore, I thought it might lead to a race condition.

Comment: Not only is `count` not thread safe (threads may see stale values), the `count++` operation is not atomic.

Comment: Oh, and `AtomicInteger` is a good way to solve the thread safety, but since Java 8, a better fit for this particular scenario is `LongAdder`.

Answer (score 1):

Integer's increment is not safe to multithreading. You should use AtmoicInteger like this:

```
public class App {

    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        App app = new App();
        app.doWork();
    }

    public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0;i < 10000;i++){
                    count.getAndIncrement();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0;i < 10000;i++){
                    count.getAndIncrement();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are printing count in main thread.
Main thread executed in its normal way , before child thread started.
That's why your count is 0 ,
 try to print count after a while , like put Thread.sleep(2000) before printing it.

Comment: Or you can check value of count in side run method. Just put a if clause in both thread if(count > 1999){
   print count....
}

Comment: Is `count++` thread safe?  If two threads attempt to do this to the same member variable at the same time, could this lead to problems?

Comment: No for now your count variable not to be called thread safe.
If you need thread safety you must use synchronized block / method.

Seems you are new in Java Threading , go with some Java Threading tutorial to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the code block which increments the count as **synchronized** in order to avoid the [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

In addition to this there are multiple ways to solve this problem- 
1. Hard code Thread.sleep(miliseconds value) in Main thread. [Not recommended]
2. join() the two threads to the main Thread so that the control returns to the main thread only when the execution of the two threads is complete.

```
public class App implements Runnable {
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        App app = new App();
        app.doWork();
    }

    public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this, "Thread - 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(this, "Thread - 2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        //1.
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        //2.
        //Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count); // Count is: 2000
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```